# Conditional filtering based on other columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to filter data by `Order_id` if `Item` contains `mm`.

```
        Order_id    Item
22565   Id20        da1
23493   Id20        mm
42094   Id20        nm
42095   Id20        be2
42857   Id24        mm
43061   Id24        ba1
43529   Id26        da1
```

For instance, `Id20` and `Id24` both contain `mm`, but not `Id26`, thus expected output:

```
        Order_id    Item
22565   Id20        da1
23493   Id20        mm
42094   Id20        nm
42095   Id20        be2
42857   Id24        mm
43061   Id24        ba1
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df1 = df[df['Item'].eq('mm').groupby(df['Order_id']).transform('any')]
```

Or:

```
df1 = df[df['Order_id'].isin(df.loc[df['Item'].eq('mm'), 'Order_id'])]
```

---

```
print (df1)
      Order_id Item
22565     Id20  da1
23493     Id20   mm
42094     Id20   nm
42095     Id20  be2
42857     Id24   mm
43061     Id24  ba1
```

Comment: Hi jezrael thanks for your solution but I think it's different from what I need. Using both methods returned data where `Order_id` did not contain an `Item` of `mm`

Comment: @nilsinelabore - Hmm, So if filter `df2 = df1[df1['Item'].eq('mm')]` It not return `mm` rows?

Comment: jezrael Sorry I was mistaken it worked, thank you!